# I get this error: BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset()

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I get in a lot of errors for my app about this, im new in coding so I would appreciate some help.

I have an app with some images that the user can set as wallpapers, the images are in drawable and I have them in a HorizontalScrollView and I have also a ImageView that shows the selected images.

This is how my Main.java looks:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView display;
int wallPaper;
private AdView adView;
Bitmap setWall2;
Bitmap setWall3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    /* START OF AdMob */

    // Create the adView
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "***************");

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    TableRow layout = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.adView);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    /* END OF AdMob */


    wallPaper = R.drawable.image1;

    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iViewMain);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image5);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image6);
    ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image7);
    ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image8);
    ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image9);
    ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image10);
    ImageView image11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image11);
    ImageView image12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image12);
    ImageView image13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image13);

    Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setWall);

    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);
    image3.setOnClickListener(this);
    image4.setOnClickListener(this);
    image5.setOnClickListener(this);
    image6.setOnClickListener(this);
    image7.setOnClickListener(this);
    image8.setOnClickListener(this);
    image9.setOnClickListener(this);
    image10.setOnClickListener(this);
    image11.setOnClickListener(this);
    image12.setOnClickListener(this);
    image13.setOnClickListener(this);

    setWall.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.image1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image1;
        break;
    case R.id.image2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image2;
        break;
    case R.id.image3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image3;
        break;
    case R.id.image4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image4;
        break;
    case R.id.image5:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image5);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image5;
        break;
    case R.id.image6:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image6);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image6;
        break;
    case R.id.image7:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image7);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image7;
        break;
    case R.id.image8:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image8);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image8;
        break;
    case R.id.image9:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image9);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image9;
        break;
    case R.id.image10:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image10);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image10;
        break;
    case R.id.image11:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image11);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image11;
        break;
    case R.id.image12:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image12);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image12;
        break;
    case R.id.image13:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.image13);
        wallPaper = R.drawable.image13;
        break;
    case R.id.setWall:

        InputStream setWall3 = getResources().openRawResource(wallPaper);
        Bitmap setWall2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(setWall3);
        try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(setWall2);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Wallpaper set!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;

    }
    System.gc();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.gc();
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    display = null;
    setWall2 = null;
    setWall3 = null;
    System.gc();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image1.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    image2.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    image3.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);
    image4.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image5);
    image5.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image6);
    image6.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image7);
    image7.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image8);
    image8.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image9);
    image9.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image10);
    image10.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image11);
    image11.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image12);
    image12.setImageDrawable(null);
    ImageView image13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image13);
    image13.setImageDrawable(null);

    display = null;
    setWall2 = null;
    setWall3 = null;
    System.gc();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you following the tutorials on Youtube? I started with some of those too, but learned some pretty inefficient coding practices in regards to composite views/ViewGroups. First, you really shouldn't be creating so many imageView objects statically and setting individual listeners to each. This is REALLY REALLY bad practice. So avoid this approach altogether. My point is, get used to doing things the correct way from now, so you won't have to come back and change/re-learn/bang your head against the wall too  much :), like I did!

You need to use a GridView, ListView, ViewFlipper, Gallery or another type of container that was built specifically for this purpose. You will constantly run into bitmap and OOM errors while using your current approach

[TUTORIAL ON GRIDVIEW](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

[TUTORIAL ON GALLERY](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-gallery-widget-example-and-tutorial/)

Comment: You also don't need to explicitly force garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks guys, I hear what you're saying. And you're correct, im trying to learn mostly by watching tutorials on youtube. Thanks for heading me in the right direction, I will try to rewrite the app.

Comment: Anytime man. Don't get me wrong btw, those tutorials are a great starting point, but they teach alot of raw techniques without getting too deep into the basics..maybe that's a good thing, because I went on to learn more and more on my own with tons of other sources. Just keep at it!

Comment: Not at all, I agree with you. It is a quick way to learn but mostly like you said its the raw techniques that they teach out. Thanks

Comment: @JadeByfield Can I bother you with this question, do you know a good way to grab the images from an online gallery? Like if I want my app to get the pictures from flickr, and then let the users set the pics as their wallpaper.

Comment: Hmmm..I remember trying to do something very similar. Have a look at this link http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/07/display-flickr-photos-in-gallery-using.html . Idk if you're trying to get images from a specific album or just the public photos on Flickr, but the latter should be easier to do!

Comment: @JadeByfield Thanks, I would like to get them from a specific album. But if i would like to get the public photos, would it be possible to gram them by tags? Like lets say I want pictures of lions.